# How can get values from dictionaries of array in python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I have array which contain some firebase datas. Inside of that array I have dictionaries. 
Here my array:

```
[{'name': 'mehmet Tilsed'}, {'name': 'mahmut Tilsed'}, {'name': 'mre Tilsed'}, {'name': 'Joe Tilsed'}, {'name': 'Joe Tilsed'}, {'name': 'Joe Tilsed'}]
```

I want to get values of each item. How can I make it?

Here my code:

```
firebase = Firebase(config)

db = firebase.database()

all_users = db.child("users").child("Joe").child("users").get()

for user in all_users.each():
   userArray.append(user.val())



item1.update(userArray[2])   // In here I take only given items value. I want to get all values.

for k in item1.values():
   print(k)

for j in userArray:
    print(j)
```

Comment: userArray.append(user.val(),get('name'))  if user.val() contains --> {'name': 'dummy'}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to print all the names from the array right? I don't know what item1 or userArray is because you left that out but this works fine:

```py
array = [{'name': 'mehmet Tilsed'}, {'name': 'mahmut Tilsed'}, {'name': 'mre Tilsed'}, {'name': 'Joe Tilsed'}, {'name': 'Joe Tilsed'}, {'name': 'Joe Tilsed'}]
for name in array:
        print(name['name'])
```

output:

```
mehmet Tilsed
mahmut Tilsed
mre Tilsed
Joe Tilsed
Joe Tilsed
Joe Tilsed
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want those in a list, you can try:

```
from operator import itemgetter

>>> arr = [{'name': 'mehmet Tilsed'}, {'name': 'mahmut Tilsed'}, {'name': 'mre Tilsed'}, {'name': 'Joe Tilsed'}, {'name': 'Joe Tilsed'}, {'name': 'Joe Tilsed'}]

>>> lst = list(map(itemgetter('name'),arr))
>>> lst
['mehmet Tilsed',
 'mahmut Tilsed',
 'mre Tilsed',
 'Joe Tilsed',
 'Joe Tilsed',
 'Joe Tilsed']
```

Or,

```
>>> lst = [dct['name'] for dct in arr]
>>> lst
['mehmet Tilsed',
 'mahmut Tilsed',
 'mre Tilsed',
 'Joe Tilsed',
 'Joe Tilsed',
 'Joe Tilsed']
```